# Controlling metamask wallet full access through website

Tags: web3js, metamask, binance

We are creating a site where we require full access to the user metamask, they will give approval of course and then we are able to trade their funds without asking every trade approval. I am sure its possible but I cant seem to find anything on it out there.

We want the user to give approval to the site having control and ability to trade funds without asking for approval again. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, and it's a good thing it isn't - because it would be trivial to exploit. Web3 isn't your target audience for this, centralized exchanges are.

Comment: No we want to trade on behalf of the wallet holder, with their approval. We are not an exchange and not wanting to be centralized.

Comment: Then consider a smart-contract controlled by a relayer node. Look into https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/.